# Помогите исправить код java

Tags: java

Написал часть кода, задача написана ниже. Но он не работает. Можете помочь.

Написать метод numJewelsInStones который принимает 2 параметра:

- String jewels: строка, каждый символ который символизирует драгоценный камень, символы уникальны
- String stones: строка, каждый символ который символизирует камень.

Строки могут состоять только из символов a..zA..Z
Метод должен вернуть количество драгоценных камней в строке stones.

Пример:
jewels = "aAb"
stones = "caсAcA"
Output: 3

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter jewels type: 'a,b,c' ");
    String jewels = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter stones type: 'a b c' ");
    String stones = s.nextLine();
    int result = numJewelsInStones(jewels, stones);
    System.out.println(result);


}

public static int numJewelsInStones(String jewels, String stones) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jewels.length(); i++) {
        String[] onejewels = jewels.split(",");
        String[] onestone = stones.split(" ");
        if (onejewels[i]!=",") {
            for (int j = 0; j < stones.length(); j++)
                if (onestone[j] == onejewels[i]) {
                    result += 1;
                }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int numJewelsInStones(String jewels, String stones) {
int result = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < jewels.length(); i++) {
   if (jewels.charAt(i)!=',') {        
      for (int j = 0; j < stones.length(); j++)
        if (stones.charAt(j)==jewels.charAt(i)) {
        result += 1;
        }
    }
   }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Поправил код123